# What is the performance impact of useContext vs props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

In a project i'm currently working on, I'm using contexts A LOT. Like: `const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext)`.

I was wondering if doing this brings a significant performance cost compared to passing down the user object through children props.

Comment: Do your actually got **any** performance issues or you do what's called "premature optimization is the root of all evil"?

Comment: @JózefPodlecki Yes 

Comment: @DennisVash totally doing premature optimization indeed, but I was also curious about this